# What's going on with this google search result..?

Tags: layout, text

Once upon a time, i came across a weird entry in google search result.

The entry would sit there strangely, with artefacts of text standing tall & vertical.

At once I fired up my trusty firebug to analyse the problem. It appeared immediate that the origin was purely in the text content, nothing could explain why it stood so tall.

I thought it puzzling that the text would suddenly change direction. I found it even more interesting that the browser would not reflow its content to adjust for it. The text just sat there, ignoring the laws of internet. Was the world falling appart? It is 2012 after all.

If seeing it in a pictogram is what you wish then to gaze at the following screenshot:

[image]

(This be Chrome (16.0.912.75 mac). This thus happens on Firefox 9 too)

If seeing it in action is what you wish then to click on the following search result link: [Search link](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22blog-index.php%22&pbx=1&oq=%22blog-index.php%22&aq=f&aqi=g-vC1&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=6847l7550l1l7932l2l2l0l0l0l0l347l668l3-2l2l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=7b82c45761e2c1b1&biw=1543&bih=1015)

What form of sorcery is causing that?

*Stackoverflow worthy* questions:

1. Why is the text direction changing without any html markup to trigger it?
2. Why is the text not forcing the browser to reflow the content and accomodate for it?

Comment: how did you get this? can you link an URL of your search?

Comment: @O.D Sorry, meant to include it. Edited the question...

Comment: This could be a question for @Jon Skeet :)

Comment: +1 This is really interessting!

Comment: Just to add to this, the site that it links to is actually just a frame with no description meta.. and the site embedded in the frame hasn't got a description either..

Comment: No problem. Thanks for working on it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's related to google, its jankenpopp.com-related, looks like one of those languages where you need to read from top to botton instead of left to right.

I was a bit sketchy to click that link...